# Customizing django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

This is my Quiz model,

```
class Quiz(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="", )
```

This is a Question,

```
class Question(Base):
    text = models.TextField()
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=question_image_path, null=True)
```

And this is an answer,

```
class Answer(Base):
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Instead of the regular django admin display I want to display the entire quiz creation form in one page. How can I customize django admin to do this.

Comment: what do you mean by ' entire quiz creation form in one page ?'

Answer (score 1):

Firstly open your urls.py file and write the path as or as you desire:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
path('', views.quiz, name = 'quiz' ),
```

Open your views.py file and write the function about your quiz:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Quiz

def quiz(request):
    allQuiz = Quiz.objects.all()
    context = {
        'quizes': allQuiz
    }
    return render(request, '<appNameInsideYourTemplatesDirectry>/quiz.html', context )
```

Now, create the quiz.html insite your templates as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
{% for quiz in quizes %}
    <li>{{quiz}}</li>
{% endfor %}    
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```